# Advanced Custom Field update_field() is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a code that changes post data and replaces them with the data of a json file:

```
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'update_post',10 ,3 );

function update_post( $data, $postarr ) {
    $postid = $postarr['ID'];
    $imdbl = get_field('imdbl', $postid);
    if ($imdbl) {
        $url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?i='.$imdbl.'&apikey=c0ceddac';
        $jdata = file_get_contents($url);
        $json = json_decode($jdata);
        $data['post_title'] = $json->Title;

        update_field('ReleaseY', $json->Year, $postid);

    }

    return $data;

}
```

Now, this code works, it gets the Title and puts it in posts title. My problem is with this part of the code:

`update_field('ReleaseY', $json->Year, $postid);`

This code replaces the value of a custom field, it works perfectly on a 'Post' post type but in other post types (in this case 'movies'), it doesn't work at all.

I don't know what the problem is and I searched all over the Internet and I tried everything.

Please help me!!

Thank you.

Comment: Please show what the value of `$postid = $postarr['ID'];` is. There might be an error there.

Comment: Also, make sure that `$imdbl` actually contains a value (which your code already does, but it won't to actually check that your movie post type actually provides said value.)

Comment: @Ivan86 Hi, i tested all of this, the ```$postid``` is ```400```, i even removed it and used the number 400 instead but it didn't work. ```$imdbl``` is also ok, the code is working ok in posts but in the custom post type it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the native WP function `update_post_meta` instead, unless you're sure ACF has loaded at the time you're trying to use the function:

```
update_post_meta( $postid, 'ReleaseY', $json->Year );
```

Reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/

Answer (score 0):

I just changed:

```
update_field('ReleaseY', $json->Year, $postid)
```

To:

```
update_post_meta($postid,'ReleaseY', $json->Year)
```

It looks good now.